# Как сделать на странице несколько таймера обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

День добр.Суть вопроса в том, что необходимо реализовать на странице несколько таймеров обратного отсчета. У каждого время отсчета должно быть различным.Плюс еще, чтобы можно было как то стилизовать эти таймеры.Пробовал различные плагины, но если таймер можно стилизовать, то два не добавишь или еще какая-то проблема.Нашел только один плагин, которые без проблем дает добавить несколько таймеров на страницу с различным временем отсчета Final-countdown - подключается просто вставкой на страницу дива с айди различными, но проблема в том, что он не создает в этом диве никаких элементов(по крайней мере через firebug или другие инспектора они не отображены), предполагаю, что вставляет просто в DOM...а я не оч дружу с js..кто подскажет решение?

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь что плагины которые вы пробовали нельзя добавить в множественном количестве, вы или неправильно их инициализировали или плохо читали документацию к ним.

Comment: Документацию читал и пробовал по разному инициализировать.Как итог было, что либо вообще не работает, либо работает один из нескольких.Поэтому и попросил тут совета.Может кто сталкивался и пробовал, если да то дали бы направление.

Comment: Хотя бы пример плагинов скиньте. В идеале еще бы пример кода с попытками подключить счетчик.

Comment: пробовал flipclock.js , countdown.js и final-countdown.js. Не сработал так как нужно ни один.Как писал ранее-final-contdown дает возможность подключить несколько(в отличии от других), но нет возможности стилизовать таймер, потому как непонятно, к каким элементам нужно применять стили.А на тему примера кода, сохраниться попытки не сохранились, а даже ели и сохранились бы, то нужно было бы целые файлы заливать, так как инициализация плагинов там проста(просто див с id) а попытки изменить что-то были в самом плагине.Но это бред я понимаю.Знаний маловато.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот к примеру countdown.js

```js
var timerId = countdown(
    new Date(),
    function(ts) {
        document.getElementById('pageTimer').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
    },
    countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);
var timerId2 = countdown(
    new Date(),
    function(ts) {
        document.getElementById('pageTimer2').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
    },
    countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);
var timerId3 = countdown(
    new Date(),
    function(ts) {
        document.getElementById('pageTimer3').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
    },
    countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countdown/2.6.0/countdown.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageTimer"></div>
<div id="pageTimer2"></div>
<div id="pageTimer3"></div>
```

Comment: окей, извини, а задать стили каждому элементу можно будет?но, всяко спасибо, думаю это решит мою проблему...я же сказал, я просто не силен в javascript...+1 к ауре!